# Why do my windows go dark when they're on my external monitor?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, screen, driver

Why is this happening? Has any one ever experienced anything like this before? Some windows stay dark on my external monitor and some come good after I let go of the cursor after dragging..

[image: Screenshot Over Laptop screen and External Monitor.]

Comment: This is happening to me too.  No idea what the cause is yet.

Comment: Same thing is happening to me, and the dark windows are, well, not blurry, perhaps not anti-aliased is the right word. Seems to be since the last software update, perhaps?  Interestingly (IMHO), the OSX windows such as Finder seem to come good fairly quickly, while third party apps (such as Chrome) are more likely to stay dark. Does this reflect your experience?

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. The only thing that works for me is restarting the affected apps.

Comment: Having the same problem, but even restarting the apps doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Check this thread out: https://discussions.apple.com/message/16608477

To quote: "...opening Display in System Settings, and choosing calibrate under Color seems to have fixed the problem."  I don't have my external monitor with me at the moment, but wil check when I'm at work tomorrow.

Comment: Recalibrating doesn't work for me. Only restarting the affected apps does.

Comment: In my case, I am not even allowed to calibrate, because "The factory profile for the display could not be found" And yet, I can see Mac correctly identifies the monitor with the right model name in the profile list